# Interpreter return "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'len' referenced before assignment" error

Tags: python

I was working on LeetCode problem [Longest Palindromic Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/description/) and had the following code:

```
    def longestPalindrome(s):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    length = len(s)
    lookup = [[False for i in range(1000)] for j in range(1000)]
    for i in range(0,length):
        lookup[i][i] = True
        longestBegin = i
        maxL = 1
    for i in range(0,length-1):
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            lookup[i][i+1] = True
            longestBegin = i
            maxL = 2
    for len in range(3,n+1):
        i = 0
        while i <= n-len+1:
            j = i + len -1
            if lookup[i+1][j-1] and s[i] == s[j]:
                lookup[i][j] = True
                longestBegin = i
                maxL = len
    return s[longestBegin:longestBegin+maxL]
```

When i call the function:`longestPalindrome('abdad')`, I got error:

*"Runtime Error Message:
Line 7: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'len' referenced before assignment".*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _Don't use `len` as a variable name._

Comment: @Rawing: it's fine in a function provided you have no intention to use the built-in; using `len` as a local, *by itself* is not the cause of the error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, it's not the cause of the error - but it's generally a good idea to avoid shadowing builtins. I suppose I could/should have elaborated a little bit on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `len` as a local variable name, by assigning to it with a `for` loop:

```
for len in range(3,n+1):
```

This makes `len` a local in the *whole function*, masking the built-in `len()` function. You can't use the name `len` both as a local and a global.

As a result, using `length = len(s)` fails because the local name `len` hasn't had anything assigned to it yet (it is not yet *bound*). Use a different name for the `for` loop target.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, that's the cause!